# Remove twitter bootstrap from Rails (added via twitter-bootstrap-rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, twitter-bootstrap

How do I remove the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem and all the assets and configurations from my rails app?

I installed it with

```
bundle install
#and
rails g bootstrap:install
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you just do this :

```
rails destroy bootstrap:install
```

and remove it from your Gemfile?